# Remove text on Comment count

Tags: comments

I have the below code which will show comment count:

```
<?php echo comments_number();?>
```

It generates output like 0 Comment, 1 Comment, 2 Comments and so on.

I just want it to show 0,1,2 etc. So I have replaced the above code to:

```
<?php echo comments_number(0, 1 );?>
```

It now works fine for 0 comments and 1 Comment replacing them as 0 and 1. But If I add the Third Value as **%s** or **%d** there in the above code to show 2 comments as 2, it is showing an error that % is not valid.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

There's is also the [`get_comments_number()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments_number/) to get only the number of comments for the post.